# DataBase Referential integrity your opinion on Log Table

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I use MS SQL 2008 and C#.

I need design a system able to Log CRUD operations on a specif table.

In my example I have two Tables:

`Articles` with `PK ArticleId`

and

`LogArticles` with a `FK to ArticleId`.

`LogArticles` is suppose to record any CRUD operations for my `Articles` table (the actual code reside in my BL no SQL).

I understand abit about *Reference Integrity* and I'm concern what is the best approach in case I delete a record from `Articles` and denying or losing of reference in `LogArticles.

Here my Ideas:

- I keep the FK on Table `Articles` and I use a CASCADE SET NULL.
- I remove the FK from Table `LogArticles` and I will just add the ArticleId without any FK to my `LogArticles`.

Please tell me what do you think about it, or any your expeirce if you have build a similar system before.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you question:

keep the structure as you described,
then add a trigger on `Article` to post the event to `LogArticles` with the current key.

Comment: Hi Randy, thanks for your comment, maybe my question was a bit foggy, now I make some tweaks and should be more comprehensible. Pleas let me know your toughs. Many Thanks!

Comment: So in your case, if I delete an Article my operation would be deny by FK in LogArticles...

Comment: you can choose - cascade the delete - set the key to null, or prevent the delete. probably set to NULL is the right choice based on your description.